# Does DPI matter for desktop in LibGDX?

Tags: java, libgdx, dpi

I am working with LibGDX at the moment.

I understand why DPI matters for android, but was wondering if it even mattered for desktop development.

My question is this, **does DPI matter at all or affect games for desktop?**

If so, is it in the same way that it does for android?

If not, how is it different?

Comment: While I'm not a gamer and can't speak from that viewpoint, DPI is definitely important to consider on desktop displays.  I have a 1920x1080 display on a 15.6" laptop screen, and due to the high (144) DPI, it's necessary to run the desktop and most applications on 125% zoom (120 DPI).  Applications that don't support hiDPI are then blurry when zooming, making it an eyesore to use them without setting them back to 144 DPI, making the contents too small for easy use.  So yes, DPI matters for the typical desktop application, especially with the 4K monitors coming out.  Just my two cents.

Comment: Most games will provide options to the user to adjust the overall resolution of the game and also adjust the UI scaling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends.

If you need to keep the same physical size across devices, then it matters. *Eg. You need an image to be 1" on both phone and tablet.*

If you need to keep the same proportions across devices and are only dealing with different aspect ratio's, then DPI will only be useful if you want to have a good idea on what a finger can achieve on a screen, which is usually 50 dp.